# Suggest email based on name

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to make a query on SQL Server 2008 that gets an email suggestion based on the `FullName` column of the `Person` table.

Ex: For the `Person` named `Rodrigo David Waltenberg` the query should return `rodrigo.waltenberg@company.com`

But I don't know how to get the fullname splitted and all lowercase. The fullname may have middlenames as well, but I need only the first and last names. Anyone knows how to do that using SQL?

Comment: ...so you want `Fullname`, all lowercase, and dots instead of spaces, and append `@whatevercompany.com`? Then why don't you just try that?

Comment: Because I don't know how to do that using sql

Comment: In SQL Server, just simple concatenations with a `REPLACE()` `LOWER(REPLACE(FullName,' ','.')) + '@example.com'`  But you would also need to check if the email is already taken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leveraging the *magic* powers of Google oftentimes helps a lot

["MS SQL lowercase string", 1st hit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174400.aspx):

```
LOWER ( character_expression )
```

turns a string to lowercase.

["MS SQL replace string", 1st hit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx):

```
 REPLACE ( string_expression , string_pattern , string_replacement )
```

replaces whatever you want with the other string you specify in the given string...

So just combine the two, and do it like this:

### Lowercasing input, and replacing spaces to dots:

```
 REPLACE(LOWER(Fullname), ' ','.')
```

If this is not enough, and only the first and last parts are neededed, leaving out the middle part is a piece of cake again.

Step 1:
 ["MS SQL index of char in string", first hit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx):

```
CHARINDEX ( expressionToFind ,expressionToSearch [ , start_location ] )
```

Step 2:

["MS SQL leftmost characters of string", first hit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177601.aspx):

```
LEFT ( character_expression , integer_expression )
```

Step 3:

["MS SQL rightmost characters of string", first hit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177532.aspx):

```
RIGHT ( character_expression , integer_expression )
```

Step 4:

["MS SQL reverse string", first hit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180040.aspx):

```
REVERSE ( string_expression )
```

If it is always true, that names have at least two parts separated by at least one space character, just plug the parts together:

### Getting first and last part of input consisting of at least two parts, lowercasing, joining them with dot:

```
LOWER(
    LEFT(Fullname, CHARINDEX(' ',Fullname)-1) + 
    '.' +
    RIGHT(Fullname, CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(Fullname))-1)
 ) + '@whatever.com' as suggestion
```

Also, if Fullname column can contain leading and trailing spaces, use a TRIM to get rid of them... That would make it go haywire...

### Full solution for any amount of parts of input string:

```
CASE 
 --when there are at least two spaces ( optimally 3 names, or double spaces between names)
    WHEN LEN(Fullname)-LEN(REPLACE(Fullname, ' ','')) >1 
    THEN 
        LOWER(
            LEFT(Fullname, CHARINDEX(' ',Fullname)-1) + 
            '.' +
            RIGHT(Fullname, CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(Fullname))-1)
         )
    ELSE
    --at most one space in name
        REPLACE(LOWER(Fullname), ' ','.')
END + '@whatever.com' as suggestion
```

And please **still** remember to *do research* and do **try something** before posting a question.

Comment: Wow! Thanks! You solved it! leftmost character... interesting. It's dificult for me to find the better keyword to search since english is not my mother language.